# How can I make my icon toggle using jQuery and MaterializeCSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In MaterializeCSS there is a specific syntax to calling their premade icons. This is an example:

```
<i class="material-icons">expand_more</i>
```

The framework knows what icon you want based on the text between the i tags. I am trying to create a collapsible div using jQuery and I would like for the icon to flip between an up and down arrow. In order to do this, I need to replace the text in between the i tags.

I am successfully able to change it once but not back when I collapse the div. Here is my code:

```js
$('.remove-text').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('collapsed');
  if ($('.arrow-change').text = 'expand_more') {
    $('.arrow-change').text('expand_less');
  } else {
    $('.arrow-change').text('expand_more');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="remove-text">
  <i class="material-icons arrow-change">expand_more</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `=` is actually setting the value, what you actually want is `==` or `===` which is a comparison.

The double equals doesn't enforce type match, but the triple does.

Also, it's `text()`, not just `text`, because you're using jQuery. If you wanted to use vanilla, it would be `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```
$( "#collapsibleDiv" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
// Animation complete.
```

});

Here is my [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/kR9ChB9VyAkKx4meKtU0/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$('.remove-text').click(function() {

var parent_child = $(this);

parent_child.toggleClass('collapsed');

if(parent_child.hasClass('collapsed')){
    parent_child.children('i.arrow-change').text('expand_less');
}else{
    parent_child.children('i.arrow-change').text('expand_more');
}

});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/r5152vna/